# How To Play Animation Through Script? - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am making a game and I made an animation for the win screen. According to all the tutorials I've watched, the animation is played when you activate the GameObject. However, it plays at the **Beginning** instead. I think the solution would be to play it separately when the game wins. Could you show me how to do that, please? Thank you in advance (:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create an Animation for a Game Object it's added as a State in the Animation Controller (Animator).

[image: Unity Animator Overview]

To Call a specific animation:

**Option A:**

You can use the Animator Component to play an animation at a specific event

[animator.Play("StateName");](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html)

**Option B:**

You can use Animator Parameters (Trigger or Boolean) to play the animation

[animator.SetTrigger("TriggerName")](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html)

[animator.SetBool("BoolName",boolean value)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetBool.html)

In Order to use the Animator Parameters, you need to define the parameters and assign them to a specific transition

In this example Once the Boolean Die is true the Animation will occur
(And in the script , you use **Animator.SetBool("Die",true)** once the health is zero)

[image: Unity Animator Conditions]

Comment: Thank You So much! Just one small question, do I need to make a reference to the animator or something like that in code? Sorry I am just learning to use the animator I am a noob ( :

Comment: You are welcome, 
So when Animator (Animator Controller) is considered to be a component,
A component can be referenced using 
1. Animator animator =  gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
2. public Animator animator; (And you can assign it in the Unity Editor Inspector)


Unity requires some learning curve at the beginning but soon you will be answering others' questions

Some Helpful links:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Components.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html


https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Components.html

Comment: OK ! Thank you for the encouragement : )